# jQuery stop at the end and return to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm quite new to jQuery and I would like to make a slider. I'm creating a slideshow that continues infinitely in the most simplest form it can. Will I have to count the number of `<li>`s or images and then get the width and append the first one to the end? Or should I use some sort of cloned function? Here's the code up to now. It rolls through the images but not continuously. I'm guessing there's going to be a lot more jQuery needed.

#### The CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#wrap{
    margin:50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul{ width:1600px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;}

li{float:left;}
```

#### The HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
   <span class="prev">PREV</span>
   <span class="next">NEXT</span>
   <ul>
      <li><img src="1.jpg" alt="image1"></li>
      <li><img src="2.jpg" alt="image2"></li>
      <li><img src="3.jpg" alt="image3"></li>
      <li><img src="4.jpg" alt="image4"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

#### The jQuery

```
$('.next').on('click', function () {$('ul').animate({left: '-=400'})});
$('.prev').on('click', function () {$('ul').animate({left: '+=400'})});
```

Comment: Your code is way to simple for what you want to do, you gonna need to keep working on it. I wrote a tutorial a while ago on how write a slider, it might help http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/07/01/how-to-create-a-slideshow-plugin-with-jquery/.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is *waaaaaaaaay* to simple for what you want to do. It is not optimal for stackoverflow as we will have to write too many code and it will be cumbersome and clumsy to change your code. You might want to see some tutorials on the web, just Google it.